# Merge Column in HTML

Tags: html, html-table

How do we merge column in HTML?

This is what I trying to achieve:
[image: This is what I trying to achieve]

**Here's my code:**

```html
<table style="width:100%" border="2px">
  <tr>
    <th>Daftar Lowongan Kerja</th>
    <th>Daftar Pelamar Kerja</th> 
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1. Junior Web Developer</td>
    <td>Januar Fahlevi</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2. Senior Web Developer</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3. Junior Java Developer</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I'm new in HTML and confused how to achieve this. I only can make 2 column, and stuck on how to create the `|S1|20 Th|Fresh Graduate|Detail` row.

Comment: use `colspan` for this

Comment: you can use the `colspan` attribute. You code doesn't match the image.

Comment: as i said, i only can make it work into 2 Column and Stuck on how to create the 'S1|20Th|Fresh Graduate|Detail| Row, and i don't know what to search besides 'Merge Col'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use the `colspan`attribute

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<table style="width:100%" border="2px">
  <tr>
    <th>Daftar Lowongan Kerja</th>
    <th colspan="3">Daftar Pelamar Kerja</th> 
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1. Junior Web Developer</td>
    <td colspan="3">Januar Fahlevi</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2. Senior Web Developer</td>
    <td>Text Goes Here</td>
    <td>Text Goes Here</td>
    <td>Text Goes Here</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3. Junior Java Developer</td>
    <td colspan="2">Text Goes Here</td>
    <td>Text Goes Here</td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this one, as  Bhargav said, you need to combine `colspan` and `rowspan` in order to achieve the desired table structure.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<table style="width:100%" border="2px">
  <tr>
    <th>Daftar Lowongan Kerja</th>
    <th colspan="4">Daftar Pelamar Kerja</th> 
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">1. Junior Web Developer</td>
    <td colspan="4">Januar Fahlevi</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
   <td>S1</td>
   <td>20 th</td>
   <td> ... </td>
   <td> ... </td> 
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">2. Junior Web Developer</td>
    <td colspan="4">Januar Fahlevi</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>S1</td>
   <td>20 th</td>
   <td> ... </td>
   <td> ... </td> 
  </tr>

</table>

</body>
</html>
```